# Postgresql hmac-sha1 signature differs from python signature

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, plpgsql, hmac

**Postgres**:

Code:

```
SELECT encode(
    hmac(
        E'PUT\n\n1\n1408355972\nx-amz-acl:bucket-owner-full-control\n/1/1', 
        '1sf235123',
        'sha1'
    ),
    'base64'
);
```

Result: `"h9wRL15mXgwRxXjqLqhbYbnfJ7I="`

**Python 3**

Code:

```
base64.encodestring(
    hmac.new(
        'PUT\n\n1\n1408355972\nx-amz-acl:bucket-owner-full-control\n/1/1'.encode(),
        '1sf235123'.encode(),
        sha1
    ).digest()
)
```

Result: `"CrU1V93ggf3QE0ovq686ir/i1ss=\n"`

I want to signed s3 upload request in postgres, but I can't get the right signature, I have tried a whole day T_T.

Can someone give me a help??? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are swapping the two first `hmac` parameters in Python. The `hmac` constructor takes the secret first

```
>>> base64.encodestring(
...     hmac.new(
...         '1sf235123'.encode(),
...         'PUT\n\n1\n1408355972\nx-amz-acl:bucket-owner-full-control\n/1/1'.encode(),
...         sha1
...     ).digest()
... )
b'h9wRL15mXgwRxXjqLqhbYbnfJ7I=\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, I am thoughtless.